# Ruby gem error: no such file to load -- bundler

Tags: ubuntu, rubygems, bundler, ruby-on-rails-3

I have some troubles with a Ruby gem named Bundler.  My OS is Ubuntu 10.04.

My environment is as follows:

```
$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.1 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 378) [i486-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby1.9.1/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/lib/ruby1.9.1/gems/1.9.1
     - /home/mo/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/

$ cat /proc/version
```

> Linux version 2.6.32-21-generic (buildd@rothera) (gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) ) #32-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 16 08:10:02 UTC 2010

```
$ ruby -v
```

> ruby 1.9.1p378 (2010-01-10 revision 26273) [i486-linux]

```
$ gem -v
```

> 1.3.6

My local gems are:

- abstract (1.0.0)
- actionmailer (3.0.0.beta3)
- actionpack (3.0.0.beta3)
- activemodel (3.0.0.beta3)
- activerecord (3.0.0.beta3)
- activeresource (3.0.0.beta3)
- activesupport (3.0.0.beta3)
- arel (0.3.3)
- builder (2.1.2)
- bundler (0.9.24)
- erubis (2.6.5)
- i18n (0.3.7)
- mail (2.2.0)
- memcache-client (1.8.3)
- mime-types (1.16)
- polyglot (0.3.1)
- rack (1.1.0)
- rack-mount (0.6.3)
- rack-test (0.5.3)
- rails (3.0.0.beta3)
- railties (3.0.0.beta3)
- rake (0.8.7)
- text-format (1.0.0)
- text-hyphen (1.0.0)
- thor (0.13.6)
- treetop (1.4.5)
- tzinfo (0.3.20)

And here is my error:

```
$ irb1.9.1 -rubygems
irb(main):001:0> require "bundler"
LoadError: no such file to load -- bundler
 from (irb):1:in `require'
 from (irb):1
 from /usr/bin/irb1.9.1:12:in `<main>'
```

I got the same error when I try to start Rails 3:

```
$ rails start
/home/mo/quick_test_2/config/boot.rb:4:in `require': no such file to load -- bundler (LoadError)
 from /home/mo/quick_test_2/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
 from script/rails:8:in `require'
 from script/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

More information about my version of Bundler:

```
$ gem list -d bundler

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (0.9.24)
    Authors: Carl Lerche, Yehuda Katz, André Arko
    Rubyforge: http://rubyforge.org/projects/bundler
    Homepage: http://github.com/carlhuda/bundler
    Installed at: /usr/lib/ruby1.9.1/gems/1.9.1

    The best way to manage your application's dependencies
```

Why do I get the error?

Answer (score 0):

**Wow!**  I don't really understand why, but new it's just fixed!  The *magic* command:

```
cp -r /usr/lib/ruby1.9.1/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-0.9.24/ /home/mo/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
```